# Calling `source` from bash function

Tags: bash, function

I'm trying to source a file whose name is passed from stdin. My plan is to create a function like this:

```
mySource() {
    # get stdin and pass it as an argument to `source`
    source $(cat)
}
```

to be called like this: `$ echo "file1.sh" | mySource` wherein `file1.sh` is:

```
FILE=success
export FILE
```

Assuming `$FILE` is initialized to `hello world`, when I run `$ echo "file1.sh" | mySource`, I expect `$ echo $FILE` to print `success`; however, instead it prints `hello world`.

Is there some way to source a file from a function?

Comment: You can first replace your `source $(cat)` with `read file; source $file`. That's the usual way to read a word from standard input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change your `mySource` function to:

```
mySource() {
  source "$1"
}
```

Then calling it with:

```
$ mySource file.sh
$ printf '%s\n' "$FILE"
success
```

You can also make `mySource` handles multiple files:

```
mySource() {
  for f do
    source "$f"
  done
}
```

Comment: Boom. That's the answer. Extra kudos for predicting the multi-file use case which I was actually trying to support. For posterity's sake, you might want to remove from the source code snippets the comment about "getting from stdin" since we're no longer doing that.

Comment: @cuonglm so is totally valid do a `source` within a method?