# Is valid use 'source' within a function?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, function

Like an introduction: if `secondary.sh` has

```
functionX(){
   ...
}
```

and `primary.sh` has - `source secondary.sh` declared - and its own functions, therefore:

```
# primary.sh content
source secondary.sh

functionA(){
   ...
}
functionB(){
   ...
}
```

According with my understanding it *is equivalent* to have copied and pasted all the source code of the former into the latter. Therefore:

```
# primary.sh content
functionX(){
   ...
}

functionA(){
   ...
}
functionB(){
   ...
}
```

Pls correct me if something it is wrong.

Furthermore the script file is executed within the current shell, any change such as environment variables are affected and reflected in the current shell. Until here I am Ok. Again, pls correct me if something is wrong.

Now, for the same `primary.sh` script file, but with a different scenario - if it has:

```
source ${SPECIFIC_PATH}/secondary.sh

functionA(){
   ...
}
functionB(){
   ...
}

startPrimary(){
 ...
 SPECIFIC_PATH="/somepath"
 ...

}
```

it fails because `source` is executed because is located at the top but `SPECIFIC_PATH` was not defined yet.

But if it is changed to:

```
functionA(){
   ...
}
functionB(){
   ...
}

startPrimary(){
 ...
 SPECIFIC_PATH="/somepath"
 ...
 source ${SPECIFIC_PATH}/secondary.sh
}
```

It works, because `SPECIFIC_PATH` was declared *and* `source` was executed at demand.

This scenario was covered here - *it is very similar*:

- [Calling `source` from bash function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150269/calling-source-from-bash-function)

But - Is it valid?

I am doing this question because my concern is:

If `secondary.sh` has functions declared and they are practically copied/pasted in `primary.sh` - In *Unix/Linux Shell Script* is valid have functions declared within other functions? I hope you see my point. I am assuming is happening the following:

```
functionA(){
   ...
}
functionB(){
   ...
}

startPrimary(){
 ...
 SPECIFIC_PATH="/somepath"
 ...
 functionX(){
   ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this for bash only? I ask because `source` isn't a standard, portable command. It is a bash-specific (and some other shells) alias for the standard `.` command.

Comment: @terdon in my case yes, for _bash_ - it for my `.sh` files, all declared with `#! /bin/bash`. So is fine use either `source` or `.`

Comment: Is it supposed to source a different secondary script each time?  If it is going to be the same each time, set your path variable before you source the script.  Also, I'm not sure how sourcing the file works exactly, but does it actually execute the functions within the sourced file, or just make them available in the calling script?  But I don't think there's any restriction over using source in a function.

Comment: @Jeter-work `Is it supposed to source a different secondary script each time?` Yes. - `but does it actually execute the functions within the sourced file, or just make them available in the calling script?` Both